# Continuous of function in a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Given the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{1-\cos(2xy)}{x^2y^2}$$
I want the function to be continuous in $(0,0)$.
If I assume that the limit when $x\rightarrow0$ equals to the limit when $y\rightarrow0$, I can easily calculate what should be the value in $(0,0)$ for continuous.
But can I assume that? I am guessing no.. So how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: First, you can define $f(x,y) = 2$ if $xy = 0$, and $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1-\cos(2xy)}{x^2y^2}$ if $xy \neq 0$. And use: $1-\cos(2xy) = 2\sin^2(xy)$

Comment: Is the limit of $\frac{sin(xy)}{xy}=1$ when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$?

Comment: Yeah but you still have the $2$ there.

Comment: Yes I know, I just wanted to know in general if it applies. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

These two remarks could also be useful:

First, note that $f$ is an even function, i.e. $f(x,y)=f(x,-y)=f(-x,y)=f(-x,-y)$. That allows you to consider only positive $x$ and $y$, i.e. you can work on the first quadrant.

Second, you can exchange $x$ and $y$, and the function remains the same. That means that you can fix $y$ first, and compute the limit of $f$ when $x$ tends to zero, and then you can compute the limit when $y$ tends to zero. It would be the same as if you fix $x$ first, and compute the limit when $y$ tends to zero, and then compute the limit when $x$ tends to zero.